# two types of row in the listview?

Tags: android, listview, button, row

I am using a listview in my Android program.

I have two types of row.
1) Only one textview and when you select it, it opens a new intent.
2) 3 textview's and a button, When you press the button it will open a new intent.

How do I distinguish these and how do I make such different things in one adapter?

P.S: I really search the internet thoroughly. I am trying to do this over 2-3 days. But no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can combine both rows in single list item an then play with visibility depending on which type of row is needed.
For example, using the layout below, you can set visibility to `View.Gone` for `row1_text` and `View.VISIBLE` for `row2_text*` and `row2_button` if you need to show ements for row2 type. And toggle the visibility for row1 type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row1_text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row2_text1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row2_text2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/row2_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row2_text3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/row2_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/row2_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/row2_text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```